# Difference in hsqldb path between mac and windows?

Tags: path, hsqldb

I am developing my webapp, which uses a hsqldb, on a mac. 
When I deploy it to windows 10, It cannot connect to (or create the) hsqldb.

This is the way I specified the path:

```
database.file=#{systemProperties['user.home']}/myrepos
```

leads to error on windows:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@715be6de[file =null, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: setPath reason: java.io.IOException: Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch (Translation: syntax for filename, directory name or the devicename is wrong)
```

How can I specify a path for hsqldb that works on every environment?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `~/myrepos` or `${user.home}/myrepos`.